# Unable to launch a fresh install of CiviCRM

Tags: drupal, installation

I installed CiviCRM over Drupal. Everything looked fine but when I want to start the module, I get a white screen and the following error when I back to Drupal. I can't enter CiviCRM.

> Warning : include(.../sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/fr_FR//%%06/069/0693F89E%%drupal.tpl.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory dans Smarty::fetch() (ligne 1264 dans .../sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php).
>
> Warning : include(): Failed opening '.../sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/fr_FR//%%06/069/0693F89E%%drupal.tpl.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:.../sites/all/modules/civicrm:.../sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages:.:.../sites/all/modules/civicrm:.../sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages:.../sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/tecnickcom:.../sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib:.:/usr/share/php') dans Smarty::fetch() (ligne 1264 dans .../sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php).

My configuration is conformed with the basic requirements asked on the wiki :

GNU/Linux 3.2.65-1+deb7u2 x86_64

Drupal 7.43

CiviCRM for Drupal 7 4.7

PHP Version 5.4.45-0+deb7u2

MySQL 5.5.47-0+deb7u1-log

pcre 8.30 enabled

I changed the permissions to 755 for the 'sites/' folder. But the error still there.

I tried before on my local machine (Debian 8 and PHP 5.6). Everything was great. Why it doesn't work on my host ?

Comment: I have the exact same issue. It's a **CiviCRM 4.7** as a plugin on a clean **WordPress 4.6.1** installation. The installation is on a baremetal, localhost on my network, a development machine. After a problem-free installation/activation of CiviCRM as per documentation, I cannot start CiviCRM. See screen below, I have the CiviCRM menu item. When I click it, the error occurs. [![WP Dashboard after clean install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMBQN.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMBQN.png) [![Error when clicked on the CiviCRM link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1gL1.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1g

Answer (score 1):

Two "simple" things jump to mind immediately.  Did you do a recursive change on the sites/ folder, chmod -R 755 sites?  Secondly, and I'd assume from the error message that you did, but you did install the l10n package, correct?

Comment: I just tried a recursive permissions change. Nothing more is happening.
I installed the l10n package but I already got the error with template_c/en_US/ ...

Comment: Hrm ... and the group, at least if not the owner also, are the web user?

Comment: I use a shared web hosting service and I think I can't change groups and owners. I just can see and change numeric permissions with my ftp client. And I don't have a ssh access.

Comment: You don't want to leave it this way, but what if you were to put everything to 777?

Comment: It doesn't work more...

Comment: Well, I guess you can earn your downgrade badge on this one then.  I'm quickly running out of ideas.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I see from the other answer that you changed the permissions - but it doesn't sound like you have the ability to edit the [umask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask).  Depending on what user your web server and PHP process runs as, this could be the issue.

Can you confirm that the files you're looking for exist on the server, and if so, who is the owner/group and what are the permissions?  After you fix the permissions, can you confirm that it's complaining about the exact same file not found, or a slightly differently named file?  If it's a differently-named file, it's probably a umask issue.  In that case, contact your shared hosting support, or find a different host if they refuse to help.

Comment: The file 'Smarty.class.php' exists and have GID: 33 and UID: 2018.
The folder 'templates_c/en_US/' exists and have GID: 33 and UID: 33.

But, there's no file in templates_c/en_US/ except a basic .htaccess with '<Files "*">Order allow,deny  Deny from all</Files>'

I tried to upload my local templates_c folder (because my local setup works). Some part of the layout are now displayed, but it's not enough to use the software.

Comment: @ben - I think uploading your templates_c is compounding the issue.  Without knowing what the UID corresponds to, it's hard to respond definitively - your host's support can help here.  But UIDs < 1000 are system accounts, and > 1000 are user accounts.  Because templates_c was created by Civi and has a UID of 33, I can deduce that your host uses mod_php or some other interpreter that runs as the web server user, not your user.  That means files uploaded by yourself won't be owned by the web server user, which is the heart of the problem.

Comment: I think your next step is either to SSH in, or ask your web host provider to resolve the permissions issue for you.